# multiple mapbox react markers saved in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add multiple markers to my map at once, but every time I add a new marker it replaces the previously placed one. I need the markers to be saved in the state so that they can all be submitted in one POST request. I have the API and Database set up, I just can't figure out this aspect of the UI.

The markers I am referring to are under the comment  {/* USER ADDED MARKER */}

Thanks in advance for any help, I have been stuck on this for days.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, Popup } from "react-map-gl";

import { listLogEntries } from "./API";
import LogEntryForm from "./LogEntryForm";

const BasicMap = () => {
  const [logEntries, setLogEntries] = useState([]);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState({});
  const [showUserPopup, setShowUserPopup] = useState({});

  const [addEntryLocation, setAddEntryLocation] = useState();

  // viewport is all the infomation about the default map state
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    latitude: 52.950001,
    longitude: -1.15,
    zoom: 6
  });

  const getEntries = async () => {
    const logEntries = await listLogEntries();
    setLogEntries(logEntries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEntries();
  }, []);

  const showAddMarkerPopup = event => {
    const [longitude, latitude] = event.lngLat;
    setAddEntryLocation({
      latitude,
      longitude
    });
  };

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...viewport}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/hidden/ck7xdy1yo1bkj1ipmsbhe9c96"
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      onViewportChange={setViewport}
      onClick={showAddMarkerPopup}
    >
      

      {/* USER ADDED MARKER */}

      {addEntryLocation ? (
        <>
          <Marker
            latitude={addEntryLocation.latitude}
            longitude={addEntryLocation.longitude}
            draggable
            onDragEnd={showAddMarkerPopup}
            onClick={() => setShowUserPopup(true)}
          >
            >
            <div>
              <svg
                className="marker red"
                style={{
                  height: `${6 * viewport.zoom}px`,
                  width: `${6 * viewport.zoom}px`
                }}
                version="1.1"
                id="Layer_1"
                x="0px"
                y="0px"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <path
                      d="M256,0C153.755,0,70.573,83.182,70.573,185.426c0,126.888,165.939,313.167,173.004,321.035
                      c6.636,7.391,18.222,7.378,24.846,0c7.065-7.868,173.004-194.147,173.004-321.035C441.425,83.182,358.244,0,256,0z M256,278.719
                      c-51.442,0-93.292-41.851-93.292-93.293S204.559,92.134,256,92.134s93.291,41.851,93.291,93.293S307.441,278.719,256,278.719z"
                    />
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </Marker>
          {/* This Popup should have its own ? statement ' is clicked ' */}
          <Popup
            latitude={addEntryLocation.latitude}
            longitude={addEntryLocation.longitude}
            closeButton={true}
            closeOnClick={true}
            dynamicPosition={true}
            // onClose={() => setShowPopup({})}
            onClose={() => setAddEntryLocation(false)}
            anchor="top"
          >
            <div className="popup">
              <LogEntryForm
                closeOnClick={true}
                onClose={() => {
                  // setAddEntryLocation(null);
                  //  getEntries();
                  setShowUserPopup(false);
                }}
                location={addEntryLocation}
              />
            </div>
          </Popup>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </ReactMapGL>
  );
};
export default BasicMap;
```

Comment: Nowhere in that code are you appending a lat/long object to your `logEntries` array; the code to do that would look something like `setLogEntries([...logEntries, newEntry]);`. Your question doesn't really have anything to do with mapbox or APIs, it's just about appending to a `useState([])` array.

Comment: I see, thanks Chris.